# How to test rest path?

Tags: java, rest, protocol-buffers

I have a  path: /widgets with post and get and I would like to test what is the response for the get /widgets rest call (expect: get 2 widgets with id and name).
And I'd like to wirte a simple junit test for this....so i call the /widgets and see what is the response. Now i tried somehow this:

```
    WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList list = ..../widgets or i dont know
    System.out.println("===== Response from GET =====");
    for (WidgetsProtoc.Widget widget : list.getWidgetList()) {
        System.out.println("id: " + widget.getId()
                + ", name: " + widget.getName());
    }
```

And the class where define the path:

```
@Path("/widgets")
public class WidgetResource {

@GET
@Produces("application/protobuf")
public Response getAllWidgets() {
    Widget widget1 =
            Widget.newBuilder().setId("1").setName("widget 1").build();
    Widget widget2 =
            Widget.newBuilder().setId("2").setName("widget 2").build();
    WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList list = WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList.newBuilder()
            .addWidget(widget1).addWidget(widget2).build();
    return Response.ok(list).build();
}
}
```

Comment: Install Postman (Chrome WebStore, or Firefox) to test RESTful API's

Answer (score 0):

Testing rest endpoints would classify as end to end test more than unit test. I Suggest exploring end to end testing tools like Robot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jetty or tomcat embedded to deploy your application in testing phase, then you just need to send a request to your web service and compare the response.

Please check the [JAXRS Testing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing) page.